# Sympy does not seem to integrate exponentials of the variable (MATLAB does it)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matlab, sympy

I am trying to integrate my function S(w)

```
import sympy as sym

w = sym.Symbol('w')
Spm = 0.95**4/w**5*sym.exp(-5/4*(0.95/w)**4)
S = sym.Piecewise(
      (Spm**sym.exp(-1/2*((w-0.95)/(0.07*0.95))**2), w<=0.95),
      (Spm**sym.exp(-1/2*((w-0.95)/(0.09*0.95))**2), w>0.95))

S_int = sym.integrate(S, (w, 0.8, 1.0))
```

It seems that `**sym.exp()` is the troubleso

me part. If I simply my function to the below, then the integral is computed successfully.

```
S = sym.Piecewise(
     (Spm**((0.07*0.95))**2), w<=0.95),
     (Spm**((0.09*0.95))**2), w>0.95))
```

MATLAB computes the integral easily with 'ArrayValue'.

```
Spm = @(w) 0.95^4./w.^5.*exp(-5/4*(0.95./w).^4);

S = @(w) ...
    Spm(w).^exp(-1/2*((w-0.95)/(0.07*0.95)).^2).*(w <= 0.95) + ...
    Spm(w).^exp(-1/2*((w-0.95)/(0.09*0.95)).^2).*(w > 0.95);

S_int = integral(S, 0.8, 1.0, 'ArrayValued', true);
```

Is there an equivalent feature in Sympy or Numpy?

Comment: What exactly does `ArrayValued` do?

Comment: I understand 'ArrayValued' generates an array of S_int values for a sequence of w's so it can integrate numerically (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html)

Answer (score 2):

The below is a possible solution for calculating the integral numerically:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

w = sym.Symbol('w')
Spm = 0.95**4/w**5*sym.exp(-5/4*(0.95/w)**4)
S = sym.Piecewise(
     (Spm**sym.exp(-1/2*((w-0.95)/(0.07*0.95))**2), w<=0.95),
     (Spm**sym.exp(-1/2*((w-0.95)/(0.09*0.95))**2), w>0.95))

dw = 0.001
len_dw = int(np.ceil((1.0-0.8)/dw) + 1)
w_arr = np.linspace(0.8, 1.0, len_dw)
S_func = lambdify(w, S, 'numpy')   # Returns a numpy-ready function
S_array = S_func(w_arr)            # S_func evaluated at w_func

S_int = np.trapz(S_array, w_arr)
```